# VirtualBox guest resolution different on external monitor

Tags: macos, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, resolution

I'm using VirtualBox 6.0.10 on macOS Mojave 10.14.5 on a MacBook Pro Retina with an internal 13 inch display, guest is Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch). I also have an external 27' monitor. If the monitor is connected to the MacBook and I run the guest full screen on the external monitor, the guest reports 1920x1280 resolution and texts with default font sizes are perfectly readable. However, if I move the guest VirtualBox window to the internal display, the resolution changes to 2560x1600 and as the screen size is about 1/4 of the external monitor, the text is no longer readable in the guest. Is there a way to force VirtualBox to use the 1920x1280 resolution in the guest in full screen mode regardless the resolution of the display on the host? It used to work fine on VirtualBox 5, but no longer works on VirtualBox 6. I have the guest additions installed and also tried to change the Graphics Controller in the Settings, but didn't help. I also set the video memory to 128 MB (just in case). I can change the scale factor every time I move the window from one monitor to the other, but it would be nice if this would happen automatically...

Comment: A solution that (IIRC) doesn’t stick is to use the VirtualBox zoom functionality. This way, you could at least read the text.